Countplotting a binary Series takes an excessive amount of time, and ends up producing a strange plot
As can be seen in the screenshot below, my y_train Series contains two values: 0 and 1. Why, then, does the countplot take almost 4 minutes to run, and when it finally finishes, it produces a plot that has nothing to do with the data?


Note that you are supposed to supply your code, and test data as text. How does y_train look like?  Probably you want sns.countplot(x=y_train).

See also issue 3654 on seaborn's github

You should directly pass the Series to x:
sns.countplot(x=y_train)

why did it fail?
Assuming the latest seaborn (0.13.2).
If you pass a Series to data, this is considered a wide format.

data:  DataFrame, Series, dict, array, or list of arrays
Dataset for plotting. If x and y are absent, this is interpreted as wide-form. Otherwise it is expected to be long-form.

import seaborn as sns

y_train = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0], name='count')

sns.countplot(data=y_train)

Output:

In your case, this creates more than 20,000 bars.
A workaround could be to convert to_frame and pass the name as x:
import seaborn as sns

y_train = pd.Series(np.repeat([0, 1], [16548, 5251]), name='count')

sns.countplot(data=y_train.to_frame(), x='count')



Thanks. What does it mean "wide format"?

It means that each value will be considered a column. This is mostly useful when passing 2D data as input.

You don't need to convert the series to a dataframe. Just pass it directly to x.

@mwaskom yes this is what I showed in the end of my answer. I added the to_frame workaround to show how this would work with data.

Sounds good, though not everyone reads the full answer apparently ;)

@mwaskom that's a fair point, I'll move it to the beginning
